# I have a problem when I try to push the data to Algolia

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, algolia

I am trying to push the data of my data base in Mysql to Algolia.
This is the code.

```
const algoliasearch = require("algoliasearch");
const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APPLICATION_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_API_KEY);
const index = client.initIndex("demo_ecommerce");
const _ = require('lodash');

var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'ecommerce'
})

connection.connect();

connection.query("SELECT * FROM productos", (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const chunks = _.chunk(res, 1000)
  chunks.forEach(chunk => index.saveObjects(chunk))
});

connection.end();
```

But when i run the code I recieved this error.

```
(node:8900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, 
use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8900) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Could help me with this? What I have to do to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your `connection.connect()` does not complete right away. Instead it uses a callback to announce its completion. But you don't have one.

That's OK, though, because `connection.query()` connects implicitly. So get rid of both `connection.connect()`  and `connection.end()` . You don't need 'em.

Second, you have the line `if (err) throw err;`  That line would be useful if your code was wrapped in a try / catch handler. But it isn't. So, when you throw an error things break.   Instead do something like this:

```
if (err) {
  console.error(err)
  return
}
```

and you'll see the error when MySQL kicks one back to you.

Third, you are misusing [the `.saveObjects()` method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/algoliasearch#-getting-started) from the algolia package. That method returns a Promise, but you don't wait for it with `.then()` or `await`.

You want to iterate over an array, calling `.saveObjects()` for each chunk. Here's the most straightforward way to do that, using an async function with an ordinary for loop in it.

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM productos", (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  saveAllObjects (res)
  .then (i => console.log (i, 'chunks saved.))
  .catch (err => console.error (err))
});

async function saveAllObjects (res) {
  const chunks = _.chunk(res, 1000)
  for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    await index.saveObjects(chunks[i])
  }
  return chunks.length
}
```

This formulation lets your async function await the completion of each `.saveObjects()` operation before it starts the next.

Be patient: it takes time to wrap your brain around Javascript's asynchronous nature.

Comment: Thank u! 
This works for me.
Now I recieved this error 

```TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value "undefined" for header "x-algolia-api-ke```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` because you are using `throw err` from inside of the callback and not handling it anywhere.

Instead, try to log it in order to see what is the actual error and properly handle it in the way which suites your application.

Comment: I did this way. 

`if(err){
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    const chunks = _.chunk(res, 1000) 
    chunks.forEach(chunk => index.saveObjects(chunk,{'autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist': true}).then(console.log(chunk)).catch(err => {console.log(err)}))
  }`

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're closing the `connection` before the query can complete.  Remove the `connection.end()` and see if that helps at all.

Comment: I removed this line, and the error it still the same.

Comment: I am using the name of the tamble in spanisH. ```productos``` is correct.